# Forcing type conversion in C++ using SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am writing a class (BufferInserter) that transparently translates user defined messages to their network endian format and packs the result into a user-supplied buffer.  Here is a simple example of a Message and its byte-swapped counterpart:

```
//Native message (not in network endian format)
struct Message
{
    short val;
    Message(short v): val(v){}
};

//Network endian format of Message
struct OtaMessage
{
    typedef Message NativeType;
    short val;

    operator Message() const
    {
        return Message(val >> 8 | val << 8); 
    }

    OtaMessage(const Message& m)
        : val(val >> 8 | val << 8)
    {}
};
```

Here is a highly simplified version of BufferInserter:

```
class BufferInserter
{
public:
    BufferInserter(char* buffer)
        :buf(buffer)
    {}

    template<typename T>
    char* insertStruct(T s, typename T::NativeType = 0)
    {
        const std::size_t size = sizeof(T);
        *reinterpret_cast<T*>(buf) = s;
        buf += size;
        return buf;
    }
private:
    char* buf;
};
```

The hope was a user could do something like:

```
Message m(1);
char buf[256];
BufferInserter ins(buf);
ins.insertStruct(m);
```

And the C++ type deduction machinery would skip passing the native Message to insertStruct because Message does not have a NativeType typedef, and instead would convert the Message to a OtaMessage.  That's not what happens, instead I get the compiler error (g++4.7)

```
test.cpp:55:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘BufferInserter::insertStruct(Message&)’
     ins.insertStruct(m);
                       ^
test.cpp:55:23: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:34:11: note: template<class T> char* BufferInserter::insertStruct(T, typename T::NativeType)
     char* insertStruct(T s, typename T::NativeType = 0)
           ^
test.cpp:34:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> char* BufferInserter::insertStruct(T, typename T::NativeType) [with T = Message]’:
test.cpp:55:23:   required from here
test.cpp:34:11: error: no type named ‘NativeType’ in ‘struct Message’
```

There is a similar error for MSVC 2013 so its probably not a compiler bug.

Obviously this works:

```
Message m(1);
char buf[256];
BufferInserter ins(buf);
ins.insertStruct(OtaMessage(m));
```

But I wanted to avoid the user having to know about the byte swapping.  I also could add a conversion operator to OtaMessage in the Message struct:

```
struct Message
{
    short val;
    Message(short v): val(v){}
    operator OtaMessage()
    {
       val = v<<8 | v>>8;
    }
};
```

There are 2 issues with this:

1. Again, I don't want the user to be aware of OtaMessage
2. OtaMessage is defined after Message so a Message-->OtaMessage is not possible.  Interestingly after trying this in MSVC 2013, I crashed the compiler:

> 1>Source.cpp(74): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
>   1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1325)
>   1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.

Any help?

Comment: This error message is relevant: `test.cpp:34:11: error: no type named ‘NativeType’ in ‘struct Message’`. You have a `NativeType` in `OtaMessage`, but the compiler is looking for it in `Message`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that.  I was hoping the C++ type deduction machinery would see that and fail when attempting to use Message as the arg to insertStruct, then find OtaMessage (cuz it does have the NativeType).

Comment: No, it's not that smart. When deducing types of template function arguments, it doesn't try to convert them first with `operator()` etc.

Comment: You may create a type trait and a helper class template which would do the conversion for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how type deduction works. Perhaps you could implement a traits-like approach, letting `BufferInserter::insertStruct<Message>` be deduced, and then convert with your traits class. Some key pieces of it might look like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct OtaConverter {
  // using ota_type = T; -- don't provide a base ota_type
};

: : :

template <> struct OtaConverter<Message> {
  using ota_type = OtaMessage;
};

: : :

template<typename T>
char* BufferInserter::insertStruct(T s, typename OtaConverter<T>::ota_type* = 0)
{
    using OT = typename OtaConverter<T>::ota_type;
    const std::size_t size = sizeof(OT);
    *reinterpret_cast<OT*>(buf) = OT(s);
    buf += size;
    return buf;
}
```

You'll also need to fix your `OtaMessage` constructor as it currently does not reference `m.val`. For safety you should also mark your constructors explicit.

See this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a87b830642c348b4). Note that removing the specialization of `OtaConverter` currently results in intentional compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I encounterd the same problem (in other circumstances) and I fixed it by updating my MSVC2013 Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Product Updates (error fixed since update 2 https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/kb/2927432).

Cheers,